# Disable warnings from within an Octave .oct file

Tags: octave, suppress-warnings

Is it possible to do this? In particular I want to toggle between warning ("off", "Octave:broadcast") and warning ("on", "Octave:broadcast"), i.e. set warning off at the beginning of the .oct file and then set warning on just before the .oct file returns its output. Of course I could do this in the terminal or in the calling script file, but I'd like to do it in the .oct file itself if possible.

Comment: the Octave broadcasting issue is only applied when it performs automatic broadcasting. Does it also works when you're in a oct file?

Comment: @carandraug Yes. This is the warning I'm getting when running the .oct from the terminal. I'm doing matrix subtraction and element division as in result = quotient( ( A - B ) , C ); where A is a one-dimensional matrix and B and C are single element matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to do it in C++, very similar to the Octave language itself.

```
disable_warning (const std::string& id);
set_warning_state (const std::string &id, const std::string &state);
```

Actually, `disable_warning` is just wrapper around the second option `set_warning_state (id, "off")`. Take a look into the [error.cc](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/df/dea/error_8cc.html) for more options related to this. I'm sure you can figure out yourself how to turn the warning back on at the end ;)